# Android: BackStack Navigation in Master Detail flow

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, fragment, master-detail, back-stack

I have problems in understanding the Up Navigation in the Master Detail Template in Android. In single pane mode (for smartphones) I use a ItemListActivity and a ItemListFragment. If a item in the ListFragment is clicked the ItemDetailFragment is called. Now if I am in this ItemDetailFragment I want to get back to the ItemListFragment by a click on the Up Navigation in the ActionBar.

I understand it like this: I just have to replace my ItemDetailFragment with the ItemListFragment, or?

In my ItemDetailFragment I use this code:

```
//OnClick auf ActionBar
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: 
          FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ItemListFragment()); 
          trans.commit();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But the ItemListFragment is then not in the state before the DetailFragment was called. I want to have the same list as before.

If I click the back button the correct action is done, so should I just implement a back click in the up navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as i understood with your description above..
>
> 1)If you click on.. in your Listfragment item then you are moving to
>   ItemdetailFragment so for that in your ListFragment you need to add
>   BackStack operation. i.e., as follows

```
transaction.addToBackStack(String);//to identify you can give any name 
transaction.commit();  //then commit the transaction
```

> 2)When you want to move from your ItemdetailFragment to ListFragment
>   you are using back button in that case in the backbutton you need to
>   call

`popBackStack("towhich screen you want to move",0) //for more information` [referthis](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,int%29%29)

Comment: I added a backstack with "up" and added this lines to my DetailFragment  `//OnClick auf ActionBar
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case android.R.id.home: 
   android.app.FragmentManager man = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
   man.popBackStack("up",0);
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }` but I still have the NullPointer Exception in the ListFragment: `feed = (RSSFeed) getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");` So the ListFragment is not the same as before, or?

Comment: Have you added addToBackStack("up"); in your ListFragment?

Answer (score 2):

with your current approach you create new instance of ItemListFragment so if you want to save the state of the list you need to do it on your own. you need to simply go back then i would suggest to invoke `onBackPressed()` method for home button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: 
          this.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had to change the line to `this.getActivity().onBackPressed();` because I call this in a Fragment. Unfortunately there is a NullpointerExcecption in the ItemListFragment. How can I simulate exactly the back click because this way it works? Do you have an idea?

Comment: hmm it is hard for me to find what causes the NullpointerException without any code of the ItemListFragment or logcat logs, but you may want to try navigateUpTo() from NavUtils. Here are docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpTo(android.app.Activity, android.content.Intent)

and here you can read more about Back vs. Up and navigation in general: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Yes I didnt want to post much of my code because the navigation works with the back button. So I thought there is an easy way to realize this in my Fragment. I will take a look at your links

Comment: Just please consider my solution more like a 'bypass' then the best option since the Up button is not equal to the back button. After you read the guidelines from the link in my previous comment you will get the difference :)